# Joomla 3.5: page displayed source until cache is cleared

Tags: php, caching, joomla

I have a weird issue where the browser returns the unformatted source code of the requested page instead of the html. The content type is set as application/rss+xml when it should be text/html. I'm running Joomla 3.5.1. As far as I know, there are no RSS feeds for the site.

This is resolved when clearing the Joomla cache, however, I haven't been able to find a way to replicate the issue so it's proving difficult to debug.

I'm not sure what other information I can provide.

Any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 0):

This is an odd problem. The fact that the backend is running fine and that "sometimes" the frontend has this problem (while the backend is fine) makes it more complicated. Does the problem happen if you disable the cache completely on your Joomla website? Also, is the problem happening on all the pages?

I suggest the next time you have this problem is to contact your host or your developer immediately, and hopefully they will be able to fix the problem. It's very hard to suggest a solution here without more context.

Note: If you were able to solve it, then please post back the solution here as it will help others.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am the developer so I have access to all the files etc. I agree, it is a difficult to suggest a solution without more context but I've been searching for weeks without any clues as to what has been happening. I realise that means you're going to struggle to help at all. I've recently turned the cache off to see what happens but I'm still waiting to get the results. I'll post anything I find.